# jquery ajax request in JSON shows error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a ajax request as below :

```
$('#student_name').change(function(){
    var student_id = $(this).val();
    if(student_id!=0){

    var url = "ajax_student_bill_details.php";
    var data = "id="+student_id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType : "json",
        data: data,
       // cache: false,
       error : function(result){
                alert('Error');
                },
        success: function(result){
                alert(result);
        } 
    });
    }
});
```

And the `ajax_student_bill_details` is :

```
$arra = ('a' => 1,'b' => 2);
return json_encode($arra);
```

But when I change the options it always alerts `Error` . Whats wrong with my codes ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N5e66/)

EDIT:

`$arra = array('a' => 1,'b' => 2);`

Comment: because your url is incorrect

Comment: same code with correct url http://jsfiddle.net/N5e66/3/

Comment: @rajeshkakawat how? I have a file called 'ajax_student_bill_details.php' in same directory

Comment: try to hit your ajax url in browser address bar see what you get????

Comment: It displays nothing ( after editing the error)!! Why so ? `var_dump` would give `string '{"a":1,"b":2}' (length=13)`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should echo your json

```
$arra = ('a' => 1,'b' => 2);
echo json_encode($arra);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure as I don't have access to your server and the fiddle was bad. I would suspect the missing protocol (http://) on your URL.

Here's a fiddle that uses http://jsontest.com and that works. Perhaps you can work from that. If you just replace your url perhaps you can see what issue is.

```
$('#student_name').change(function(){
var url = "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two";
var data = "id=1";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType : "json",
    data: data,
    // cache: false,
    error : function(result){
     alert('Error');

    },
    success: function(result){
        alert('Ok');
    } 
});
});
```

Comment: yeah its working I can see. So the problem is ith the `url` I guess. Whats wrong with the `json_encode` for the above array in my question? It displays nothing when I tried to see what it returns